# Groovy Template Engine rendering contents

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to separate some contents in the body section of my *layout.tpl*. For instance, I have carousel slider in my *index.tpl*, but it's not necessary to include it inside the *login.tpl*. Moreover, I need to add another page specific contents too. So, *layout.tpl*, and *index.tpl* are like in the following:

**layout.tpl**

```
  body {
    headerContents()
    div(class:'container') {
        div(class:'row') {
            div(class:'col-lg-12') {
                content()
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

**index.tpl**

```
layout 'layouts/layout.tpl',
title:'Home',
headerContents: contents {
   h1('Test Header')
}
content: contents {
   h1('Test Content')
}
```

But `h1('Test Content)` cannot be rendered. I checked the docs but I couldn't find anything about how to render two different contents. Does template engine support to do this or not?